# Cant load model after adding custom component in pipeline(spaCy)

Tags: python, spacy

I trained a NER from scratch with custom dataset without any other component in pipeline. I loaded the model and added another component(Phrase Matcher) to existing pipeline and trained NER again.Now I cant load the new saved model.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deusxmachine/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 19, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/deusxmachine/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 116, in load_model
    return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **overrides)
  File "/home/deusxmachine/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 156, in load_model_from_path
    component = nlp.create_pipe(name, config=config)
  File "/home/deusxmachine/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 215, in create_pipe
    raise KeyError("Can't find factory for '{}'.".format(name))
KeyError: u"Can't find factory for 'my_component'."`
```